# Get really usable area of a Groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

In Windows Forms, when I position a label control at `Y=0` inside a groupbox, then the label intersects with the title text on top of the groupbox.

How can I get the usable area within the `Groupbox`, i.e. the are that's not obstructed by the title text of the box?

Setting `control.Y = groupBox.Padding`.Top doesn't work. And `Groupbox.ClientRectangle` doesn't take the text into account either.

[image: Explanation]

Edit: There is an easy hack to get that inner rectangle: Simply position one `Label`in the `GroupBox`, and set it's `Dock` property to Fill. Then you can get the relevant information (Top/Bottom/Left/Right) from the Panel, or simply use the panel directly to add your child controls.
However, I'd still like to know how to get those coordinates without such hacks.

Comment: There's no property for this, it is always eyeballed in the designer.  You'll need to measure the text height yourself, TextRenderer.MeasureText().

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [DisplayRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle.aspx) property:

> The DisplayRectangle property returns the client rectangle of the display area of the control. For the base control class, this is equal to the client rectangle. However, inheriting controls might want to change this if their client area differs from their display area. The display rectangle is the smallest Rectangle that encloses a control and is used to lay out controls.

Example:

```
label1.Location = groupBox1.DisplayRectangle.Location;
```

Comment: The DisplayRectangle returned does not respect the lower bounds of the Text property of the GroupBox when you have changed the font to 20 em via code.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky Still works for me with `groupBox1.Font = new Font(groupBox1.Font.FontFamily, 20);`, then I did `groupBox1.Text = groupBox1.DisplayRectangle.ToString();` and it returns a location of (3, 34).  Placing a panel inside that group box at that location did not overlapped the enlarged caption.  You will have to give me code that duplicates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Quite old thread, but here is what I use for my controls :

```
label1.Location = new Point(0,(int)(groupBox1.Font.Size)*2);
```

[image: HeaderWithBigText]

[image: HeaderWithSmallText]

And this is how it looks with  different text sizes.